# Clickonce for multiple computers

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I used ClickOnce for sometime. It works perfectly.
However, i am now having problem when i want to publish it to multiple computers from 1 same source.

The connection string which i wrote at the App.COnfig is pointing to the specific computer name. Everytime when i publish, that connectionstring will be published as well. Now problem comes when i want publish to multiple computers. It will definitely trigger error as they are not sharing the same Computer name in the connectionstring

Could you advice?

-------EDIT-----------

Hi i read some post and it refer me to use mageui.exe.  Does that help in solving my problem as this problem still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Use a user-setting instead (via a `.setings` file). When your app loads, check the setting; if it is missing/blank display a dialog to enter the server name (etc), and use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to form that into a connection-string. Now store that as the setting and save (it should now reappear next time they load).

You might also want to make that available via an options menu somewhere.

Comment: Ok, this sound new to me. Let me go explore and test it out. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Marc Gravell: When u say store as the .settings, do u meant store the connectionstring in the Properties->Settings.settings ? If there are multiple computers, i will write each computer connectionstring in that .settings file?

Comment: @belinq I'm saying "let the user enter the DB info"; if you need to define all the configurations up front, the a *resource file* (resx) with some kind of file with the machinename/connection combinations would be good.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I got what your meant now. But how do i save the DB info to the .settings file at run time? i would imagine now to click on the "Configuration" at the menu, and prompt a form to ask for the Db connectionstring. Then save it. Could you share some light how to run time save that? Also, would it still be possible if i do this alteration to a software which i have already deployed?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Is this a good way to save  it to .settings? http://bhrnjica.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/handling-with-connection-string-at-run-time-in-developing-the-desktop-applications/

Comment: @belinq if that allows per-user, maybe; I'd have started from a .settings myself, though

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I am afraid i don get you on your last reply. Could you show me a tutorial link on how to save the db info to the .settings file at run time?

Comment: @belinq - this is VB and 2005, but it still applies: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/appsettings2005.aspx

Comment: @Marc Gravell: i downloaded the program and tested but it did not save anything to the setting file. Seem like the program is not working